# Why use minify tools like Grunt, cssnano and Gulp when there are online minifiers?

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, gulp, minify

I'm working on improving the loading speed of my site, and one of the things I need to do is minify all my CSS/JS.

I see sites online to minify these files in a matter of seconds, so I'm wondering why there is a need to use technologies like Grunt, cssnano and Gulp. I don't think these technologies would minify these files on page load every single time, because that would add extra overhead, so I'm struggling to find the advantage of using it. Maybe if there are hundreds of files to minify then I can see the advantage, but I'm working with less than 10 css files.

Comment: You really prefer to manually copy through an online tool every time you change anything? **Why?**  The point of these tools is _automation_.

Comment: It does whatever you set it up to do, *re: your edit.*

Answer (score 1):

The advantages ? Point 2 of the Joel test: Build in one step.

You can have complex projects with large code base and the only thing you have to build it is to run:

```
npm run build
```

Then deploy ...

Answer (score 0):

Task runners like ( gulp, grunt, Webpack) are very useful for a hundred of purposes. Even in tiny projects you can get advantages like:

**Performance**: 
In this fields there's not much to explain, using tools for concateneting and minifying results in less archives and less requests, all in one bundled.

**Readability**: 
In your development environment you can read the whole code and use tools to lint and/or validate them, very useful to avoid further problems!

**Scalability**: 
This is the most important IMO, working a running project with a task runner means (if build correctly) in a nice code to apply to another projects or maybe the same in a bigger scale.

**Organization/Saving Time**:
 With modules to modularize HTML for example you can just include "pieces" of the DOM and load in any page you want! Imagine for example you have a section called "sale 01" and they are appended in 50 html pages, imagine how crazy would be if you just edit your sale01.html and all the page that loads this content were changed!

**Hot/Live reloading**:
 When you change the code you don't need to reload the browser, the task runner do this for you.

You can automate your process, once it's configured.

[Nice article saying about gulp](https://appendto.com/2015/08/why-use-a-task-runner-like-gulp/). I don't know how is your build environment so I cannot say what tool fits for your purpose, but with online tools it's not the best manner to automate your processes.

UPDATE 1: 
*Does it minify the css/js prior to a new page load or does it minify them once and create a new directory with the minified files to be used later on?*
***YES***
Does it re-minify once it detects that the files have been changed?
***YES, if you setup for this. Here I just minify when build the project, it saves me time.***

Answer (score 0):

It's all about automation and reducing the number of steps to generate the need files/resources. Most often it's as simple as a save on a CSS/JS/HTML(template) file that will run minification, concatenation, file generation etc.

Other times it's a simple command you run like `grunt build` that does a bunch of different things to build the files you would need for a production environment.

I personally use *Grunt* and always watch for saves on my CSS, JS and template files.

A couple basic examples:

**CSS**

You update a couple property values in `style.css`. As soon as you save the changes, *BOOM!* `style.min.css` is generated. The benefit is you didn't have to copy-n-paste to the web (from your post I'm guessing you're doing this 10 times), minify and then copy-n-paste from web to local file.

Also, you typically want to cache bust CSS files. You do that by adding the cache busting value to the filename or as a query param. The task runner will also do this when you save your changes, *BOOM!* `style-12345.min.css` created or `?v=12345` is updated in the template automatically. All **you** had to do is hit `CTRL+S` for all that to happen or type and run a simple command (`grunt css`).

There's also CSS pre-processors out there like SCSS and LESS that allow you to use variables, functions etc. in your CSS. The task runner can process these files before you perform concatenation, minification etc. Again, all **you** had to do was save a file and it all happens in the background.

**JS**

You have a couple widgets for your site. You can write and store all your code in `script.js` or you can save each widget (among other scripts) in their own files and combine them all into one file. If you have a task runner and you store your scripts in separate files as soon as you change one, *BOOM!* `script.min.js` is generated. Prior to minification you might have made a save to `a.js` which caused `a.js`, `b.js` and `c.js` to be combined, linted (verify code quality) and minified.

---

You also don't have to worry about if you copy-n-pasted each file properly or you even saved the minified result, it all just happens.

There's many things that can be auto-magically done with your files, all with a simple save and **no other action** on your part required.

Answer (score -1):

Why copy everything when Gulp or Grunt can do this automatically for you? You can also specify in which folder and or file the compiled code should be placed. And you can compile all your scripts or stylesheets into 1 file. So you can reduce the calls the browser makes to your files. They compile on file change so you won't even notice it ;)

Answer (score -2):

There's a huge difference between where you started with this question ("why would one use these tools when online minifiers exist?") and where you ended up with it ("why should *I* choose to use these tools when online minifiers exist?").

I can't speak to what works for your build process, so if you want to manually feed each file through an online minifier I'm not going to tell you not to.

But why one might choose a tool like grunt:

Because it can be made part of a repeatable automated build process, which might be broader than just minifying client-side resources.

Yes, it might matter more if you have more resources.  But it also might matter more if you expect to do more than just one production release.  Or for any reason that people might care about build automation, really.